# Django get_form_kwargs() not being called

Tags: python, django

I have a view that has 3 sections. The top section is a search area. The bottom left section shows a list of objects and the right section shows the details of the selected object.

My view inherits from ListView and FormView.

```
class SearchViewMixin(FormView):
    template = 'template here'
    form_class = forms.SearchForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        print 'This is not being called'
        kwargs = super(SearchViewMixin, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['search-units'] = self.request.search.unit_set.all()
        return kwargs

class ListView(ListView, SearchViewMixin):

    def get_queryset()...
    def get_context_data()....
```

The form view is this:-

```
class ReceiptSearchForm(BaseForm):

    obj_id = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    unit = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, required=False, empty_label='Select a unit',
                                  widget=core.SelectPickerSearch)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.units = kwargs.pop('search-units', None)
        super(ReceiptSearchForm, self).__init__()
        self.fields['unit'].queryset = self.units
```

The problem is the get_form_kwargs method is not being called. The print statement is not getting executed

Since I am not writing or updating any data, I am just using a get method for the form.

Comment: Your inheritance is a complete mess - you create a template view and treat is as mixin, while it's just a view, and then you pass it as a parameter to the view as a mixing - you have to refactor it - see an example http://django-vanilla-views.org/  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/

Comment: Thanks. I am a newbie to django and I am adding this search feature to a pre-existing project where the above-mentioned ListView is inheriting from 6 more views which in turn are inheriting from 2 -3 views each.

I finally figured this out, but now the form.unit.queryset is always empty in the html template ??

Comment: form.unit.queryset  is used with formsets - see examples http://www.effectivedjango.com/forms.html